# Pandas replace empty with value based on column using dictionary

Tags: pandas, replace

I have a dataframe with a few dozen columns. I'd like to replace NaN or empty values with a specific number or string, depending on the column. Is there a dictionary approach that would work? Dictionary example below, not sure how to apply it to a dataframe. Using Python 2.7

```
mydict ={'ColA': -999, 'ColB': -888, 'ColC': 'TBD'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `pandas.DataFrame.fillna`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': [1, np.nan, 3], 'ColB':[10, np.nan, 30], 'ColC':[100, np.nan, 300]})
mydict ={'ColA': -999, 'ColB': -888, 'ColC': 'TBD'}
new_df = df.fillna(mydict)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    ColA   ColB ColC
0    1.0   10.0  100
1 -999.0 -888.0  TBD
2    3.0   30.0  300
```